# How can I install multiple rxjs dependencies required by app?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm, rxjs

I'm building an app using Ionic which requires multiple dependencies. When I install the dependencies manually and then `npm install` I get this message in the terminal

```
npm WARN @angular/common@6.0.9 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.0.0 but none is 
installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/core@6.0.9 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.0.0 but none is 
installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/forms@6.0.9 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.0.0 but none is 
installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/http@6.0.9 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.0.0 but none is 
installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ngrx/store@6.0.1 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.6.0-forward-compat.0
^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN videogular2@6.3.0 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.0.0 but none is 
installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ videogular2@6.3.0
updated 1 package and audited 12368 packages in 18.832s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

This is how my `package.json` looks at the moment
[package.json(A)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQDJH.png)
[package.json(B)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSGAH.png)

When I manually added the require rxjs versions, I kept getting the same errors for other packages. Also my rxjs globally installed version is `6.2.0`but it obviously needs to be a much lower version in order to prevent some of the errors. However I am having trouble uninstalling this version despite using `--force`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use [rxjs-compat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-compat) for version requires < 6.0.0

Comment: I updated it and I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: You have both of them install right? `rxjs` and `rxjs-compat`

Comment: yes both the `rxjs-compat` automatically installed as a `devDependencies`